# Too much time spent in compilation

Tags: compiling, mathptmx

I have created my thesis and I have a problem enough annoying. I have created the appendix of my thesis and put into all tables. I used as font `mathptmx`. When I try to compile it takes so much time about 40 minute. This is a part of my main file:

```
...

\usepackage{mathptmx}

...

\begin{document}
  \input{appendix}
\end{document}
```

When I comment that line or use another font, I got a fast compilation. I don't know the reason. The problem is I can't post all the appendix because there are too many table. What do you suggest to solve the problem?I have to use `mathptmx` so I can't change font

**EDIT**

LOG FILE ->
http://pastebin.com/yc0Fc3zd

Comment: This is going to be hard to help with without seeing some form of example. Could you give a short demo of one of the tables?

Comment: Yes sure I can give you an example...

Comment: mmm there is another problem that making me crazy. I created a working MWE including only the necessary packages and the compilation time is normal. Instead when I include it with all my thesis it takes so time. The fact is I'm pretty sure that it depends on the appendix because when I remove it, the compilation time return normal.

Comment: Now I post the log file. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/yc0Fc3zd

Comment: Well, there are lots of errors flagged up! Wild guess: does your appendix contain lots of tables typeset using `siunitx`? If so, take a look at the 'speeding things up' section in the `siunitx` manual.

Comment: Errors? Where? Apart \hbox what are the others errors? yes I use siunitx.I didn't find that section in siunitx manuale

Comment: Opps, misread some pdfTeX info. The section in the `siunitx` manual is 7.9, 'Maximising Performance', p. 69 in current release.

Comment: Ok I read that section. I add the comand parse and something else but I got the same result: long compilation time.

Comment: A comparison with a log file with a different font might be helpful. Btw, are these `nullfont` warnings expected?

Comment: No that nullfont I don't what they are

Comment: Using `microtype`'s [latest beta](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/ruid=4713746492/action=view/id=569) instead of version 2.4 should also help.